# KendoUI - grid - style default edit, delete, update and cancel buttons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I change default edit, delete, update and cancel button and replace them with buttons with my icons ?

My command code:

```js
command: [
        {
            name: 'edit',
            template: "<a if-role-permission=\"['PERMISSION_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_DELETE']\" class='k-grid-edit k-grid-update k-button'  style='width: 26px; height: 26px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>"
        },
        {
            name: 'destroy',
            template: "<a if-role-permission=\"['PERMISSION_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_DELETE']\" class='k-grid-delete k-button'  style='width: 26px; height: 26px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></a>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

This is only for kendo grid add button,

```
 .k-add
 {
  background: url("/Content/images/loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important      
 }
```

**Grid**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
 column:[{command:[ {
                     name: 'edit',
                     template: "<a if-role-permission=\"['PERMISSION_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_DELETE']\" class='k-grid-edit k-grid-update k-button'  style='width: 26px; height: 26px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>update</a>"
                     },
                     {
                     name: 'destroy',
                     template: "<a if-role-permission=\"['PERMISSION_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_DELETE']\" class='k-grid-delete k-button'  style='width: 26px; height: 26px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span>cancel</a>"
                     }]}]
});
```

**Note :** If you do this it effect all your `grid add` button icon.

Comment: I think it will only change icon on button (it is ok that change this buttons in whole app) . But How can I remove text from (update, cancel) buttons ?

Comment: I want to do this in command buttons (see my question , I past my code) . I have only two command buttons in my grid(edit and destroy). They change to update, cancel in edit or create mode. I want to remove their labels.

Comment: @lukisp see my code. now it display `update` and `cancel` as button text.

Comment: as i say befeore **I want to remove their labels** not to edd. In normal (read) mode I don't see labels (used template) but when I click on edit ison (to edit inline row), the button changed to update and cancel with labels. **I want to change icons, and remove their labels**

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the following style:

```
.k-button {
    min-width: 32px !important;
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

You might narrow it to your grid or even to some buttons.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/wv2x2uxv/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can just hide text via css

```
.k-grid tbody .k-button {
   min-width: 12px;
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columns : [
{ title: "&nbsp;", width: "83px", template: "<a class='k-button' name='DeleteButton'><span class='k-icon k-i-x'></span>Delete</a>" }
]
```

This will give a button that can have any wording (put text between span tags), the icon given is k-i-x, this is the delete button icon from Telerik...you can find more [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/icons-web).

This button can then be referenced by name, or if you give it an ID it can be referenced by that.
It doesn't need to be within command to clarify.